# How to access array boolean value -- array required, but Object found

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble accessing an array Boolean value such as the following...

```
boolean[][] sub = new boolean[][];
Object[] record = new Object[];

record[0] = sub;

if ( record[0][0][1] == false )
{
    // Do something
}
```

When I set a watch, I get Type of boolean and value of false.
The compiler gives an error of array required, but Object found.

The record[] array is of type object but contains a `boolean[][]` array within each index. I have tried casting but it isn't working ( i.e. `(boolean)record[0][0][1]` ). Does anyone have ideas on how to access the boolean value?

Comment: definition of record please

Comment: post here record definition...

Comment: record definition post here please here

Comment: Did you try ((boolean[][])record[0])[0][1]?

Comment: A lot of code / information is need to come up to a correct wanted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each element of `record` is `boolean`, the casting should be done on the first access to **that** array:

```
if ( ((boolean[][])(record[0]))[0][1] == false )
{
    // Do something
}
```

Or better yet, instead of comparing to `false`, just evaluate the array's content:

```
if ( !((boolean[][])(record[0]))[0][1] )
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: just remove the == false and put a ! infront